# Postman request doesn't work - Rest APi implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, postman, spring-rest

I have a problem to create a POST or a GET request in postman. I have an controller that suppose to save a new project or to receive all projects from DB.
If I try to save a project in a class that implements CommandLineRunner in database  it's everything ok. For more extra details I put my code below:

This is Project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")

public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "proj_id")
    private int projectId;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String projectName;

    @Column(name = "dg_number")
    private int dgNumber;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "variant_gate_relation",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "proj_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "gate_id")}
    )
    private Set<Gate> gates = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "variant_threshold_relation",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "threshold_id"))
    private Set<Threshold> thresholds = new HashSet<>();

    public Project() {

    }

    public Project(String projectName, int dgNumber, Set<Gate> gates, Set<Threshold> thresholds){
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.dgNumber = dgNumber;
        this.gates = gates;
        this.thresholds = thresholds;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ProjectController.PROJECT_URL)
public class ProjectController {

    public static final String PROJECT_URL = "/cidashboard/projects";

    @Autowired
    private final ProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectController(ProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Project> getAllProjects(){
        return projectService.findAllProjects();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Project getProjectById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return projectService.findProjectById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
 //   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Project saveProject(@RequestBody Project newProj) {
        return projectService.saveProject(newProj);
    }
}
```

This is my CommandLineRunner

```
@Component
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

        private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

        private final GateRepository gateRepository;

        private final ThresholdRepository thresholdRepository;

        public Test(ProjectRepository projectRepository, GateRepository gateRepository, ThresholdRepository thresholdRepository) {
            this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
            this.gateRepository = gateRepository;
            this.thresholdRepository = thresholdRepository;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            Gate gate1 = new Gate("gate5", 23);
            gateRepository.save(gate1);

            Threshold threshold1 = new Threshold(101, "threshold5");
            thresholdRepository.save(threshold1);

            Set<Gate> gates = new HashSet<>();
            gates.add(gate1);

            Set<Threshold> thresholds = new HashSet<>();
            thresholds.add(threshold1);

            Project project1 = new Project("project1", 20, gates, thresholds);
            projectRepository.save(project1);

            List<Project> allProjectsFromDatabase = projectRepository.findAll();

            System.out.println("List of all projects from database : ");

            for (Project project : allProjectsFromDatabase) {
                System.out.println(project.toString());
            }

            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

            List<Gate> allGatesFromDatabase = gateRepository.findAll();

            for (Gate gate : allGatesFromDatabase) {
                System.out.println(gate);
            }
        }
    }
```

My output from console is :

```
1 project1 201 gate5 23.0 threshold5 101
```

I try to do this request from Postman:

```
  {
   "projectName": "project2",
    "dgnumber": 1,
    "gates": {
        "gateType" : "gate2",
        "gateValue" : 13
    },
    "thresholds": {
        "thresholdType" : "threshold2",
        "thresholdValue" : 22
    }
 }
```

And I receive the following output :

```
 {
    "projectId": 3,
    "projectName": "project2",
    "dgnumber": 1
}
```

And in DB only in project table the data was save, in gate table, threshold table, variant_gate_relation and variant_threshold_relation didn't  save nothing

Comment: "Postman request doesn't work", considering you get a result and not an Exception, I somewhat assume it does work. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: in DB only in project table the data was save, in gate table, threshold table, variant_gate_relation and variant_threshold_relation didn't save nothing

Comment: So how is it a problem with Postman and REST implementation? If the data is getting saved in one table but not others, isn't it a problem with the persistence layer?

Comment: I don't know what to say... because if I try to save a Project object from CommnadLineRunner the data is save in all the tabels

Comment: It is that way because you configured it to be like that. Your `Project` has `@ManyToMany` without any cascading, so no addition/changes to entities in that collection will be persisted.

Comment: The `CommandLineRunner` "works" because you individually save the references entities. I you would remove that, construct only a `Project` and **ONLY** persist the `Project` it would behave exactly the same. The issue is with how you configured your matings NOT with Postman or the REST request.

Comment: Ahhh.. i understand, i modify the Project entity and I added the Cascade type:
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "variant_gate_relation",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "proj_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "gate_id")}
    )
    private Set<Gate> gates = new HashSet<>();
and the output is the same...

Comment: M.Deinum, I removed the save method from CommandLineRunner, and I left only the method that save Project object but in database the data was save ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CommandLineRunner`, you do this before saving the project.

```
        Gate gate1 = new Gate("gate5", 23);
        gateRepository.save(gate1);

        Threshold threshold1 = new Threshold(101, "threshold5");
        thresholdRepository.save(threshold1);

        Set<Gate> gates = new HashSet<>();
        gates.add(gate1);

        Set<Threshold> thresholds = new HashSet<>();
        thresholds.add(threshold1);
```

You should replicate that when saving from endpoint as well (the `gateRepository.save()` and `thresholdRepository.save()` are relevant here).

Comment: Hi, Alex! 
Is not this thing done when I save the project object? I say this because I have @ManyToMany relationships...Ok, and this is for the POST request, however for the  GET request when I want to see all the projects in the database I don't get any information about Gate or Threshold. Is it something wrong in my endpoints, or something in my entities?

Comment: Regarding the saving part, considering the `CommandLineRunner` behaves as expected (all data is saved in the database) and the `saveProject` from `ProjectController` does not behave as expected (no data is saved in gate and threshold table), I would suggest replicating the same logic from the `CommandLineRunner` in the REST controller `saveProject` method (i.e. persist the gate and threshold and afterwards persist the project).

Comment: Regarding the reading part, entities mapped by @ManyToMany are lazily loaded by default (hence, they are not loaded from the database when you fetch the project, and therefore do not appear in the response). In order to fetch them eagerly, take a look at entity graphs.

Comment: For documentation regarding entity graphs, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ section `5.3.10. Configuring Fetch- and LoadGraphs`.

Comment: And I see no problem with your endpoints, so my guess would be it is either the mappings on the entities or the repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your advice  I did what you told me and finally I realized the mistake. I didn't do well the request from postman  and I don't know why but 
I had to change fetch = FetchType.EAGER with @Lazy Collection (LazyCollectionOption.FALSE).

Comment: Glad I could help!